# The signal is very weak here, but the signal is stronger here

Tags: word-usage

If I get around four or five signal bars at a region,can I use the following sentences:

> 1.)The signal is very strong here.
>
> 2.)The signal is very good here.

And if I get a very poor reception:

> 3.)The signal is very weak here.
>
> 4.)The signal is very bad here.

And if I don't get a signal on my phone at all:

> 5.)There is no signal here.

And then my friend comments somewhere in a distance at the same place:

> 6.) But there is signal here.

Do all the 6 sentences sound natural? If any of these don't sound natural, what can be an alternative? So what would be used by you?

Answer (score 1):

They sound natural and are natural. But they also lack some information. Example, signal is weak here and strong here? Where exactly? Have you identified the actual location? Are you pointing to two different spots?

Also, question 6. Your friend says "But there is signal here" He could be standing an undefined distance, which essentially could be a spot you declared to have a strong signal. It gets confusing.

Comment: Actually..... She's standing at a distance from me at the same place. So does the 6th sentence in that context sounds natural?@TurkuSama